# Selectpicker Menu Wont Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a simple dropdown-menu with bootstrap and put a selectpicker menu inside of it.

When I click on the select menu everything works fine. However if I don't select anything from the select menu and click outside the bootstrap dropdown, the menu stays.

Any ideas how i can get the select menu to also close when the dropdown closes?

See code example: https://jsfiddle.net/yw0cw028/

```
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">test</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div style="height:150px; width:250px">
      <select name="test" class="selectpicker" data-size="3">
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit">Change</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    container: 'body',
    dropupAuto: false
  });

  $('body').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.parents('.bootstrap-select').length) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('.bootstrap-select.open').removeClass('open');
    }
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of interest:

in order to close the rendered select, after clicking on it and then clicking  outside the dialog, you need to listen for the dialog hide event:

```
 $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
```

Your approach ($('body').on('click', function(event) {...) is wrong.

To close the rendered select you can remove the class open:

```
$('.bootstrap-select.open').removeClass('open');
```

It's necessary to change the function:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

because this function must be used to take track if you clicked the selectpicker or not.

So the snippet is (your updated jsfiddle is: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/yw0cw028/17/)):

```js
// take track if you clicked in the dialog inside the selectpicker area
var selectpickerIsClicked = false;

$(function () {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    container: 'body',
    dropupAuto: false
  });

  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.bootstrap-select.open').is(':visible') || $(e.target).closest('.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-default').is(':visible')) {
      selectpickerIsClicked = true;
    }
  });

  // when the dialog is closed....
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    if (selectpickerIsClicked) {
      e.preventDefault();
      selectpickerIsClicked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">test</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div style="height:150px; width:250px">
            <select name="test" class="selectpicker" data-size="3">
                <option value="1">Test 1</option>
                <option value="2">Test 2</option>
                <option value="3">Test 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit">Change</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help gaetano! Ok this solved the problem of the select menu staying open however now when you click back in to the dropdown it has lost the selectpicker styling of the select menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again. Can you please help me because when I remove the script I wrote from the html and just keep your script that you wrote in the javascript window (in jsfiddle) it doesnt work anymore. Why is this?

Comment: Also when I select an item in the select menu, the select menu does not close anymore.

Comment: @Chris.P. Sorry for the delay. I updated the answer and the jsfiddle. Let me know. I tested it and all now works fine.  Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks a lot, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the bottom of your script section

```
  $('ul > li').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown').dropdown('toggle');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by stop propagating the events from the child of "dropdown-menu" and closing the open menu by clicking on it anywhere else. Hope this will help.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     $('.bootstrap-select.open').removeClass('open');
     }).find('.btn-group').on('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
  });

 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    container: 'body',
    dropupAuto: false
 });

 $('body').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.parents('.bootstrap-select').length) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.bootstrap-select.open').removeClass('open');
    } 
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yw0cw028/8/